# how to set mongoose schema for select option list and set property on selected option

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema()

const productSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name : {
            type: String,
            required : true
        },
        price : {
            type : Number,
            required : true 
        },
```

> Blockquote  here select option for units eg - KG, liters, meters, cm

```
    }
)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mongoose doesn't have the select type and you need to manage the drop-down in you view, but you should define a set of the property so that only those properties will be accepted by that field, by **ENUM**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema()

const productSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name : {
            type: String,
            required : true
        },
        price : {
            type : Number,
            required : true 
        },
        units: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['KG', 'liters', 'meters', 'cm'],
            required : true 
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: gotcha ty..
can i access enum list as an array in the front end ?

Comment: From MongoDB schema you can't get it in the frontend, you need to manage it in your config manually.